# python time delta - inclusion of hour to date

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I have files in an S3 bucket. The data files are named with a date on the end of a standard label.

For example, a file key looks like this:

`test_file_2016-12-01.tar.gz`

I wish to download files from date `x` to date `y`. I can do this like so:

```
conn = boto.connect_s3(host="s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com")
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)
k = Key(bucket)
key_prefix = "test_file"
date_o = date(2016,11,30)
date_1 = date(2016,12,01)
day_delta = date_1 - date_o
for i in range(day_delta.days +1):
    file_key = key_prefix + str(date_o + td(days=i)) + "tar.gz"
    # Get the file
    k.key = file_key
    # Location for download destination
    temp_location = "./tmp/" + file_key
    k.get_contents_to_filename(temp_location)
```

However, I am now harvesting finer resolution data and wish to add data with hour resolution.

Thus the files look like this:

`test_file_2016-12-01-10.tar.gz`

I can handle time delta's well using the `timedelta` feature of `datetime` but this does not support `hour` as well.

How can I adjust this to specify capturing the files between something like:

```
date_o = datetime(2016,11,30,01,0,0)
date_1 = datetime(2016,12,01,12,0,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, the `datetime` module will convert `timedelta` hours into seconds, which means that we have to first complete the calculation in seconds and then divide back by 3600 to get our desired range of hours. After that, we just need to supply `strftime` with our desired format as we iterate in order to display individual hours.

```
import datetime as dt

date_o = dt.datetime(2016, 11, 30, 0)
date_1 = dt.datetime(2016, 12, 1, 0)

delta_hours = (date_1 - date_o + dt.timedelta(hours=1)).total_seconds() / 3600

for hour in range(int(delta_hours)):
    current_time = date_o + dt.timedelta(hours=hour)
    file_name = 'test_file_' + dt.datetime.strftime(current_time, 
                                                    '%Y-%m-%d-%H') + '.tar.gz'
    print(file_name)
```